# Why telegram bot does not respond?

Tags: heroku, telegram-bot, webhooks

I'm developing a simple API in NodeJS + a telegram bot client in php.
The project is hosted with Heroku with webhook method.

The telegram bot is not responding?

This are the heroku logs of my app:

```
heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/index.php" host=movie-bot-prova.herokuapp.com request_id=9f6da3f1-22c8-4844-804c-7ce15a7fed83 fwd="91.108.6.67" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=1ms status=404 bytes=393 protocol=https
```

This is the Procfile

```
web: node server.js
```

This is the package.json

```
{
  "name": "progetto_pdgt",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "* [F..... O....... matricola n°286732] (https://github.com/Franci-75)",
  "main": "server.js",
  "devDependencies": {},
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "node server.js"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://github.com/Franci-75/movie-bot-prova.git"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/Franci-75/movie-bot-prova/issues"
  },
  "homepage": "https://github.com/Franci-75/movie-bot-prova#readme",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.18.1",
    "axios": "0.27.2"
  }
}
```

This is the response of "getWebhookInfo" of my Telegram bot

```
{"ok":true,"result":{"url":"https://movie-bot-prova.herokuapp.com/index.php","has_custom_certificate":false,"pending_update_count":11,"last_error_date":1657647343,"last_error_message":"Wrong response from the webhook: 404 Not Found","max_connections":40,"ip_address":".............."}}
```

**What am I missing here?** **It doesn't tell me anything, I don't know where I might have gone wrong?**

Comment: The requests from Telegram to your webhook were clearly not successful, as you can see by the 404 status code. Are you sure your webhook is `https://movie-bot-prova.herokuapp.com/index.php` and not for example `https://movie-bot-prova.herokuapp.com/api/telegram...`?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you made it in the right way, but the first thing I want to check to help you is how to set webhook, do this (obv put there your token and the https page of yourn script):

```
https://api.telegram.org/bot   TOKEN   /setWebhook?url=   THE SCRIPT ON YOUR HOST (USE HTTPS)
```

Example

```
https://api.telegram.org/bot43h45ui5h123443/setWebhook?url=https://www.example.com/index.php
```

Just digit in on web

Comment: I verified, I think I did it well but thanks for the answer anyway

Comment: If the problem is with the webhook idk what you need to do more than this, I'm sorry